# jQuery.validator rule for not checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I would like a jQuery.validator **rule** for a checkbox that is not checked. Below is what I have if the checkbox is checked, but I can't figure out the syntax for a rule for not checked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
rules: {
    sbPhone: {
         required: "#sbPhoneMe:checked",
         phoneUS: true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `:not()`

```
rules: {
    sbPhone: {
         required: "#sbPhoneMe:not(:checked)",
         phoneUS: true
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with that syntax, but jQuery has a selector ":checked" you can use to determine if an element is checked or not.

```
$(".inputButton:checked")
```

That selector above will select all elements with a class of 'inputButton' and has the checked property true.